# Ruby on Rails: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError for team_id that shouldn't be needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Minimum Viable Example

### Models

#### Team:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users, through: :team_memberships
    has_many :team_memberships
    has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

#### User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
    has_many :team_memberships
```

end

#### Relation:

```
class TeamMembership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :team
end
```

### Database

#### Schema:

```
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "uuid-ossp"

  create_table "team_memberships", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["team_id"], name: "index_team_memberships_on_team_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_team_memberships_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "teams", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "tier"
    t.integer  "users_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_teams_on_users_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", using: :btree
  end
```

#### On Disk:

```
select * from teams;
 id | name | tier | users_id | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+------+----------+------------+------------
(0 rows)

select * from users;
 id | name | email | password_digest | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)

select * from team_memberships;
 id | user_id | team_id | created_at | updated_at 
----+---------+---------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

### Error

This:

```
@user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user_user@example.com", password: "foobar23", password_confirmation: "foobar23")
@user.save

@team = Team.new(name: "Example Team", tier: 0, owner: @user)
@team.save

@membership = TeamMembership.new(user: @user, team: @team)
@membership.save
```

Throws this:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `team_id`
```

For this line:

```
@team = Team.new(name: "Example Team", tier: 0, owner: @user)
```

## Confusion

I have no idea why a `team_id` is needed, or where to put it.
The team database has an `id` column for itself, yet the error seems to suggest it also needs a `team_id` column?

I understand the [Active Record Association](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) for `has_one`, and thus the `teams` database has a `user_id` for the owner.

Comment: Is this error happens when you run tests? `test/test_helper.rb:16:in setup_helper`

Comment: Yes, it also happens when I execute the commands manually via `rails console --sandbox`

It happens on **all** tests because the error is on the `setup` phase of the tests where I said it throws it.

I can paste the output, but its the same error message I pasted here many times over.

Comment: what happens if you first create the membership and than the team? I am thinking because of the has_many through relationship for user and team ... not sure

Comment: The membership is invalid, so `@membership.save` fails. After that, running the `@team = Team.new(name: "Example Team", tier: 0, owner: @user)` throws `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'team_id'`

So, nothing different.

Comment: I did this: http://pastebin.com/AvAnBUAS, commenting out all the code around `team_membership` and its relations, and I still get the error, so I doubt it has anything to do with `team_membership`

Comment: `Team_Membership.new` is this a spelling error or your real code, because it should be `TeamMembership.new`

Comment: Fixed, no change in errors. I'm 90% it's **something** to do with the `owner` tag, but I've tried modifying it every which-way I can think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association definition

```
# class Team
has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

makes Rails think `users` has a `team_id` column.

Calling

```
@team = Team.new(name: "Example Team", tier: 0, owner: @user)
@team.save
```

makes Rails try to set the team_id attribute of `@user` to the new Team's id.

You may wish to redefine your `:owner` association as

```
# class Team
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
```

which will require an owner_id column on the teams table.

Comment: Now I seem to be getting `block in` errors. Hrm.

Thank you though, I appear to be getting closer!